# Mockito @Mock object returns the same object irrespective of new when..return definition Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit5

So, Consider the following Scenario :

```
@Service
class Series{

    private DateMgr dt;

    public Series(DateMgr dt){}

    public List<LocalDate> calculate(Frequency f,Boolean always){
        List<LocalDate> dates = dt.getDates(f,always); //ISSUE!!!
        //process on dates
        return dates;
    }
}
```

Now, consider a test for the same :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public TestSeries{
    @Mock
    DateMgr dt;

    @InjectMocks
    Series s;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup(){ 
        //some setup 
    }

    //method for producing n number of dates
    public List<LocalDate> getMockDates(int c){}

    //mock dt.getDates(f,always) function call
    public void mockDates(List<LocalDate> dates){
         when(dt.getDates(any(),anyBoolean())).thenReturn(dates)
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
         List<LocalDate> dates1 = getMockDates(2);
         mockDates(dates1);
         List<LocalDate> processedDates = calculate(param1,param2);
         //some assertions
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
         List<LocalDate> dates2 = getMockDates(3);
         mockDates(dates2);
         List<LocalDate> processedDates = calculate(param1,param2);
         //some assertions
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is that in the test2 too, when the function reaches the point of dt.getDates(f,always), it still returns the list of two dates i.e. the mock when then definition of first test. Can you please help me identify what I am missing?

I have tried resetting the mock object after each test but still it doesn't work.

I am expecting that when the test2 runs, dt.getDates(f,always) should return dates2.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but you might need to call `Mockito.reset(dt)` before setting up your new `when...`

Comment: Why do you `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`?

Comment: And please make sure that your [mre] is syntactically correct and actually compiles

Comment: @aeskreis I cannot reproduce, the code from the question (once all compiler errors and missing classes were fixed) works and uses 2 and 3 dates respectively. I'd still suggest to get rid of `PER_CLASS` as this could lead to lots of unexpected and hard-to-debug problems.